# Systemd not working after Ubuntu 14.04. to 16.04. upgrade

Tags: systemd, upstart

I just did the above mentioned upgrade but it seems like systemd is not working as it should. If I run a command like `systemctl start apache2` I get the message

> Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

Oddly `service apache2 start` is still working. I had to start the upgrade twice because something went wrong the first time I did, so I think it might have something to do with that.

Is there a way to manually switch from upstart to systemd while maintaining all working services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transition is described in an [Ubuntu guidance document](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers), called "Systemd For Upstart Users."

Comment: I saw that article already, but got confusion by the headlines.

**"If you want to switch back to systemd, install the systemd-sysv and ubuntu-standard packages."**

That did the trick. Thank you very much!